# is Google Bigquery suitable for inserting data from IoT devices?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am working on a startup company where we would sell an IoT device of some sort . these devices will be connected to our server hosted in Google cloud and will send data every 1 second where my server will store it in database as a time series. Let's say we have 1000 device connected and all are sending their data every second , Is it suitable to use google bigquery to insert these data in table every second for each device to it's corresponding table to the owner of the device ?

since my data is in form of a time series i am thinking of using partitioned table for each user ( owner of my device ) but with the limits and quotas listed in the official documentation i am worrying of reaching the limit with my high number of inserts every second ( not to say that I will query the data based on user demand on my phone app ) .

if it's not suitable what would be suited for my use case ?

EDIT : my main concern is the huge amount of inserts per second which can exceeds BigQuery limits or might cause slow down since it's mainly for data warehouse . BigTable seems expensive for us and CloudSQL it seems the way to go but we are worried of slow query times once the table get filled since i am inserting 86400 row per user per day .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [`CLOUD IOT CORE`](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core/) - fully managed service to easily and securely connect, manage, and ingest data from globally dispersed devices

> Device data captured by Cloud IoT Core gets published to Cloud Pub/Sub for downstream analytics. You can do ad hoc analysis using Google BigQuery, easily run advanced analytics and apply machine learning with Cloud Machine Learning Engine, or visualize IoT data results with rich reports and dashboards in Google Data Studio.

Check also [`IoT Core with PubSub, Dataflow, and BigQuery`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-y3s6XY70Os)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am aware of it , my main concern is the huge amount of inserts per second which can exceeds BigQuery limits or might cause slow down since it's mainly for data warehouse . BigTable seems expensive for us and CloudSQL it seems the way to go but we are worried of slow query times once the table get filled since i am inserting 86400 row per user per day .

Comment: Going through IoT Core, and by extension, Pub/Sub, then using Dataflow to push from Pub/Sub to BigQuery means your scalability of handling the inserts per second goes pretty much sky high. Dataflow can batch insert into BQ also to help with any potential quotas you might hit.